# No Method Error Rails(Method is there)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When running my tests I keep getting a NoMethodError undefined method 'mutual_friendship'

I cannot figure out the reason, I have a block in my test that calls this method and passes with no problem, then I add this new block which calls it and it throws this error yet the test before it using the method still works just fine.  Any Ideas?

This error ends up being on line 116. The whole block is

```
   should "delete the mutual friendship" do
      assert_equal @friendship2, @friendship1.mutual_friendship --line 116
      @friendship1.delete_mutual_friendship!
      assert !UserFriendship.exists?(@friendship2.id)
    end
```

Now this is in my UserFriendship.rb file

```
    def mutual_friendship
      self.class.where({user_id: friend_id, friend_id: user_id}).first
    end
```

The odd thing is I call this method in the block below which passes and is before the block erroring out.

```
 should "accept the mutual friendship" do
  @user_friendship.accept!
  assert_equal 'accepted', @user_friendship.mutual_friendship.state --method called!
 end
```

The @friendship are defined as such:

```
@friendship1 = users(:user1).user_friendships.where(friend_id: users(:user2).id).first
@friendship2 = users(:user2).user_friendships.where(friend_id: users(:user1).id).first
```

Comment: undefined method on? what is `@friendship1` defined as? Can we get the full error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sevenseacat is hinting to, @friendship1 is probably not of class UserFriendship. At line 115, add

```
assert_not_nil @friendship1
assert_instance_of UserFriendship, @friendship1
```

Comment: It indeed was nil!  When I was defining my instance variables I forgot to put the @friendship1 = and just had friendship1 =

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to tell with the code you've provided, but I'm going to guess that the `@friendship1` instance variable isn't actually an instance of the `UserFriendship` class.

You might be calling `mutual_friendship` on an empty result instead -- that would happen if the `users(:user1).user_friendships.where(friend_id: users(:user2).id)` code returned no results for the `first` call to work with.